# Page not scrolling down

Tags: html, css

CSS

```
       * {         
            moz-box-sizing: border-box;
           -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body {
            background-color: #25274D;
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
        }
        #header {
            background-color:;
            position:fixed;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:100%;
        }
        #link {
            text-decoration: none;
            color:whitesmoke;
            float:left;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight:700;
            padding-right:1vw;
            padding-left: 1vw;
            display: block;
            transition: 0.4s;
            height:100%;
        }
        #link:hover {
            background-color: #464866;
            color:#2E9CCA;
        }
        a:link, a:visited {
            line-height:7vh;
        }
        #top__nav {
            text-decoration: none;
            height:7vh;
        }
        #top__nav__menu {
            position:relative;
            display:block;
            list-style-type: none;
            padding-left: 60vw;
            height:7vh;
            background-color: #25274D;
            margin-top:0;
        }
        #logo {
            float:left;
            position: absolute;
            left: 1vw;
        }
        #revealCard {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #25274D;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100vh;
            z-index: 1;
            float: left;
            border:1px solid #464866;
            perspective: 1000;
        }
        #card {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transition: all 0.4s linear;
        }
        #revealCard:hover #card {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
        .face {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            color:#2E9CCA;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
        .face.back {
            display: block;
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            color: #2E9CCA;
            text-align: center;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 20px auto;
        }
        #img {
            width:100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #dynamicText {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: 30vh;
            font-size: 40px;
            position:absolute;
            margin-top:20px;
        }
```

I have a top navigation bar and then two divs which rotate and show the content behind like two faces of a card, below it I need to implement some other functionality but the text is coming on top of content rather than below it.

```
 <div id="header">
        <div id="top__nav">
            <div id="card">
            <ul id="top__nav__menu">
                <img id="logo" src="Logo.png">
                <li><a id="link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a id="link" href="#">Free Trial</a></li>
                <li><a id="link" href="#">Samples</a></li>
                <li><a id="link" href="#">Q-Bank</a></li>
                <li><a id="link" href="#">Help</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div id="revealCard">
                <div id="card">
                    <div class="face">
                        <p>Hey, hover to see the image.</p>
                    </div>
                <div class="back face center">
                    <img id="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1419064642531-e575728395f2?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=67fd942ed774f3de1db50cf3dd0065eb&w=1000&q=80">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div id="revealCard">
                <div id="card">
                    <div class="face">
                        <p>Hey, hover to see the image.</p>
                    </div>
                <div class="back face center">
                    <img id="img" src="http://country.southafrica.net/country/cache/ce_img_cache/local/country/uploads/images/Garden-Route_640_480_90_s_c1_c_t.jpg">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="dynamicText">
        <p>Signup For Your Free Beta Trial Today!</p>
        </div>
```

The text in the div dynamicText is shown on top of the content, rather than below it. I want it as a normal scrolling page with scroll. I think there is some problem with position property. Please have a look and tell me what is the fix?

Comment: You have a lot of duplicated id, it is not allowed, they should be unique, use class instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is edited code:

HTML

```
<div id="header">
   <div id="top__nav">
     <img id="logo" src="Logo.png">
     <ul id="top__nav__menu">
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Free Trial</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Samples</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Q-Bank</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Help</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="revealCard">
   <div class="card">
     <div class="face">
         <p>Hey, hover to see the image.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="back face center">
         <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1419064642531-e575728395f2?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=67fd942ed774f3de1db50cf3dd0065eb&w=1000&q=80">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="revealCard">
  <div class="card">
     <div class="face">
         <p>Hey, hover to see the image.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="back face center">
         <img class="img" src="http://country.southafrica.net/country/cache/ce_img_cache/local/country/uploads/images/Garden-Route_640_480_90_s_c1_c_t.jpg">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="dynamicText">
   <p>Signup For Your Free Beta Trial Today!</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {         
        moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #25274D;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
    }
    .link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color:whitesmoke;
        float:left;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight:700;
        padding-right:1vw;
        padding-left: 1vw;
        display: block;
        transition: 0.4s;
        height:100%;
    }
    .link:hover {
        background-color: #464866;
        color:#2E9CCA;
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        line-height:7vh;
    }
    #top__nav {       
      text-decoration: none;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 100;
      background-color: #25274D;
    }
    #top__nav__menu {
      display: flex;
     justify-content: flex-end;
      list-style-type: none;
      background-color: #25274D;
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
    #logo {
        float:left;
        position: absolute;
        left: 1vw;
    }
    .revealCard {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #25274D;
        width: 50%;
        height: 300px;
        float: left;
        border:1px solid #464866;
        perspective: 1000;
    }
    .card {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: all 0.4s linear;
    }
    .revealCard:hover .card {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    .face {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        color:#2E9CCA;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .face.back {
        display: block;
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        color: #2E9CCA;
        text-align: center;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 20px auto;
    }
    .img {
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #dynamicText {
        max-width: 100%;
        font-size: 40px;
        color: white;
    }
```

Also check it at  [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pZERwV)

1. Classes are used instead of duplicated ids
2. Changed html structure, admitting you want top menu fixed on top, and other content, uncluding cards with images scroll.
3. Relative height units replaced by absolute  `.revealCard` (originally you used 100vh which means 100% of viewport height - one of the reasons of your ussies)
4. set fixed position to  `#top__nav`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `position: absolute` from the dynamicText, and then do `float:right` in revealCard instead of `float: left`.

Also, you should not use the same id more than once.  If you're going to use the same name, change it to a class.

Hope this helps!